# Correct syntax for two id's with Knockout.JS link

Tags: syntax, knockout.js, hyperlink

Ok, so I'm able to create a link using one id :

```
<td><a data-bind="text: productTypeId, attr: {href: '/*******WebAdmin2/ProductManager/ProductTypeDescriptionEditor.aspx?ProductTypeID=' + productTypeId}" target="_new"></a></td>
```

But what is the correct synatx for referencing two id's in a link?

```
<td><a data-bind="text: wsNotes, attr: {href: '/****webadmin2/Common/PopupWindows/ManufacturerBlurbEditor.aspx?manufacturerid= + manufacturerBlurbID, &stylecode=styleCodeId'}" target="_new">Edit Blurb</a></td>
```

Sorry! I'm still very new to KO. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<td><a data-bind="text: wsNotes, attr: { href: '/****webadmin2/Common/PopupWindows/ManufacturerBlurbEditor.aspx?manufacturerid=' + manufacturerBlurbID + '&stylecode=' + styleCodeId }" target="_new">Edit Blurb</a></td>
```

A better way would be move the url creation logic from the view to your viewModel, something like:

```
var MyViewModel = function (data) {
    this.styleCodeId = ko.observable(data.styleCodeId);
    this.manufacturerBlurbID = ko.observable(data.manufacturerBlurbID);

    this.manufacturerUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        return '/****webadmin2/Common/PopupWindows/ManufacturerBlurbEditor.aspx?manufacturerid=' + this.manufacturerBlurbID() + '&stylecode=' + this.styleCodeId();
    }, this);
};
```

And in your view you reference it like this:

```
<td><a data-bind="text: wsNotes, attr: { href: manufacturerUrl }" target="_new">Edit Blurb</a></td>
```